# How to check if user owns ERC1155 token from specific contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, erc-1155

I have a ERC1155 collection on opensea and I am trying to perform a check in my contract to see if the user owns any tokens from the collection, and how many. With ERC721 I was able to do this but I'm having issues with ERC1155 balanceOf -

```
require(IERC1155(0x00...).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 1, "No tokens owned!");
```

I don't have the exact tokenID because it varies depending on what the user owns. How can I perform a check?

**EDIT**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract test is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {

using Strings for uint256;

constructor() ERC721("TEST", "TEST") {}

function viewBalance() external view returns (uint256) {return IERC1155(contractAddress).balanceOf(userAddress,tokenID);}

}
```

contractAddress, userAddress, tokenID - used as placeholders for the post. I'm placing the values directly in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to specify token id in erc1155. There is no way for doing it to a standard erc1155 contract.

Comment: I tried it but for some reason I'm getting an error - `Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1.` Any ideas as to why?  `balanceOf(wallet_address, tokenID);` https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155#IERC1155-balanceOf-address-uint256-

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct interface or abi?

Comment: I believe so. I added my code in the question to show what I'm using

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it resolved. Thanks.

Comment: That is interesting. I didn't see any problem with your code. What was the problem?

Comment: it was a simple dumb error on my part. The contract and token ID were mainnet and I was testing on rinkeby. Oof. Now I'm on to my next issue lol

Comment: lol. I'll check out your new issue.